# Super Reduced String python

Tags: python, string

I've been having problems with this simple hackerrank question. My code works in the compiler but hackerrank test is failing 6 test cases. One of which my output is correct for (I didn't pay premium). Is there something wrong here?

**Prompt:**
Steve has a string of lowercase characters in range ascii[‘a’..’z’]. He wants to reduce the string to its shortest length by doing a series of operations in which he selects a pair of adjacent lowercase letters that match, and then he deletes them. For instance, the string aab could be shortened to b in one operation.

Steve’s task is to delete as many characters as possible using this method and print the resulting string. If the final string is empty, print **Empty String**

**Ex.**

**aaabccddd → abccddd → abddd → abd**

**baab → bb → Empty String**

Here is my code:

```
def super_reduced_string(s):
    count_dict = {}
    for i in s:
        if (i in count_dict.keys()):
            count_dict[i] += 1 
        else:
            count_dict[i] = 1 

    new_string = ''
    for char in count_dict.keys():
        if (count_dict[char] % 2 == 1):
            new_string += char

    if (new_string is ''):
        return 'Empty String'
    else:
        return new_string
```

Here is an example of output for which it does not work.

```
print(super_reduced_string('abab'))
```

It outputs `'Empty String'` but should output `'abab'`.

Comment: Refer to the [Super Reduced String Solution in C and Python3](https://github.com/strikersps/Competitive-Programming/tree/master/Hacker-Rank/Super-Reduced-String) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a counter, your program loses track of the order in which it saw characters. By example with input `'abab'`, you program sees two *a*'s and two *b*'s and deletes them even though they are not adjacent. It then outputs `'Empty String'` but should output `'abab'`.

## *O(n)* stack-based solution

This problem is equivalent to finding unmatched parentheses, but where an opening character is its own closing character.

What this means is that it can be solved in a single traversal using a stack.

Since Python can return an actual empty string, we are going to output that instead of `'Empty String'` which could be ambiguous if given an input such as `'EEEmpty String'`.

#### Code

```
def super_reduced_string(s):
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        if stack and c == stack[-1]:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            stack.append(c)

    return ''.join(stack)
```

#### Tests

```
print(super_reduced_string('aaabab'))     # 'abab'
print(super_reduced_string('aabab'))      # 'bab'
print(super_reduced_string('abab'))       # 'abab'
print(super_reduced_string('aaabccddd ')) # 'abd'
print(super_reduced_string('baab '))      # ''
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with recursion:

```
def superReducedString(s):
    if not s:
        return "Empty String"
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if i < len(s)-1:
            if s[i] == s[i+1]:
                return superReducedString(s[:i]+s[i+2:])
    return s
```

This code loops over the string and checks if the current and next letter/position in the string are the same. If so, these two letters/positions I get sliced from the string and the newly created reduced string gets passed to the function. 
This occurs until there are no pairs in the string.

TESTS:

```
print(super_reduced_string('aaabccddd')) # 'abd'
print(super_reduced_string('aa')) # 'Empty String'
print(super_reduced_string('baab')) # 'Empty String'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a list and then add only unique letters and remove the last letter that found on the main string. Finally all the tests passed!

```
def superReducedString(self, s):
    stack = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if len(stack) == 0 or s[i] != stack[-1]:
            stack.append(s[i])
        else:
            stack.pop()
    return 'Empty String' if len(stack) == 0 else ''.join(stack)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a while loop to keep cutting down the string until there's no change:

```
def superReducedString(s):

    repeat = set()
    dups = set()
    for char in s:
        if char in repeat:
            dups.add(char + char)
        else:
            repeat.add(char)

    s_old = ''        
    while s_old != s:
        s_old = s
        for char in dups:
            if char in s:
                s = s.replace(char, '')
    
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 'Empty String'
    else:
        return s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solved With a while loop and string slicing!

```
def superReducedString(s):
   
    retString = s
    i=0

    while i < len(retString)-1:
        if retString[i] == retString[i+1]:
            if i == 0:
                retString= retString[2:]
            else:
                retString= retString[:i] + retString[i+2:]
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1   
    
    return retString if retString else "Empty String"
```

It passes all the test cases :)